# Android TextView not show Complete long Text

Tags: android, textview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:padding="2dp"
              android:background="@drawable/cell_background">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I came across a problem,`TextView` not showing the complete text and I absolutely cannot limit text length in code (not other things either!).

When I use `setText` with the following string：

> qwertyuyiopasdfghjklkjsdfhvrtcgwrgcrcrfcwerm,fixcumreiovtreuiocfmruefcmeroiwurewmiohgxiehgiocwrhhhhwemoggruiohwgcioweruhcmrehxrmeihouxe,horhxihuxchfjkhjklsdfhdlkfhdsjflkasdhjfhaskldfhdkljfhsadjfkhdsjfdsakflajdasghsdlkacvnsadohlkfjhdjkflsadhkjfhasdlkfhdsjlkfhdjlkfhasdjfhicnerjsdklfhdjsklfhdsjklfhasdjklvcnsldkjfldksfhajsldkfhdjklsjfhasdjklf789456123

it only shows:

> qwertyuyiopasdfghjklkjsdfhvrtcgwrgcrcrfcwerm,fixcumreiovtreuiocfmruefcmeroiwurewmiohgxiehgiocwrhhhhwemoggruiohwgcioweruhc

[image]

but `getText` returns the complete string as shown on the `Hierarchy Viewer` screenshot!

[image]

Comment: Actually I re-set the layout params in code so that there is enough space to set text. But the problem is TextView got enouth space to display the text, but it just not show complete text.------plz refer to the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text is too long try to put the text view in scroll

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.bala.computer.thenaliramanstories.ScrollingActivity">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/txtStory"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: any other solution? I want to find out why cannot show full text! As far as I know TextView can show more text than this.

Comment: Thanks， But I found some codes lie in the deep corner:  textView.setMaxLines(6);-----My fault!

Answer (score -1):

Change your **LinearLayout's** `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Comment: sorry, I add an image , Plz have look at the image[1]. I don't think that is the problem

Comment: Actually I re-set the layout params in code so that there is enough space to set text. But the problem is TextView got enouth space to display the text, but it just not show complete text.

Answer (score -1):

Your parent view has a width of 100dp.

```
android:layout_width="100dp"
              android:layout_height="50dp"
```

Change them to match_parent and it should be fine

Comment: sorry, I add an image , Plz have look at the image[1]. I don't think that is the problem